# Mass Assignment issue with `updateOrCreate` in Laravel, why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mass-assignment

I have a very simple model:

```
class Employee extends \Eloquent
{
}
```

And what I would like to do is to synchronize the local data with the ones stored in a remote server. In my MySQL I have

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
```

So I am sure that if I match on `id`, I would never do mass assignment.

So when I do:

```
foreach((new RemoteEmployee())->all() as $emp) {
    Employee::updateOrCreate(['id' => $emp['id']], [
        'firstname' => $emp['id'], 
        'lastname' => $emp['lastname'], 
        'phone' => $emp['phone']
    ]);
}
```

I should not get this error:

```
Add [id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Employee].
```

Anyway, if I modify my model as follow:

```
class Employee extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = ['*'];
}
```

I do not get any errors, but my entries are null.

Why?

Comment: does fillable property accept wildcards?

Comment: Good question, I also tried with just `['id']`. Same on me if I have to mention every column in my Model.

Comment: but you are also filling firstname, lastname and phone.

Comment: But I am not doing mass assignment :(

Comment: I think you should not use id in that query. Because the first array makes the updateOrCreate set the id column which has an autoincrement property (I guess). You should search for first and last names, or do a separate query to the database.

Comment: Well, I think the main problem is that `id` is not AI. I use the same unique value as used in the remote DB.

Comment: Is it a primary key?

Comment: Yes it is as mentioned in my question `PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)`

Comment: Would you consider adding an remoteId column to your Employee table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184559/discussion-between-nowox-and-taha-paksu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First exclude the id from the fields

Second if you want to allow all fields use `protected $guarded = [];` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set at least 1 item in `$fillable`, Eloquent will stop throwing the mass assignment exception. It will, however, ignore any fields that are provided for mass assignment that are not included in `$fillable`. So it is effectively ignoring everything, since `'*'` is not supported by Eloquent in `$fillable`.